# Best way to read in large amounts of data

Tags: matlab

Just wondering what the best way to read in large data files into MATLAB is? I'm currently reading in large .txt files as a table and combining them together based on their date. The problem I'm having is that MATLAB is running out of memory and I'm not sure the best way to get around this.

The Files I am reading in have structured headers and are in the following format:

```
Phone timestamp;sensor timestamp [ns];channel 0;channel 1;channel 2;ambient
2021-03-04T19:58:47.117;536601230968690944;-332253;-317025;-322290;-641916;
2021-03-04T19:58:47.124;536601230976138752;-332199;-316980;-322281;-641938;
2021-03-04T19:58:47.131;536601230983586560;-332214;-316982;-322224;-641979;
2021-03-04T19:58:47.139;536601230991034368;-332200;-316973;-322191;-641939;
2021-03-04T19:58:47.146;536601230998482176;-332160;-316958;-322216;-641963;
```

Comment: Do you need the whole set of data in memory in the end or can you process and "forget" about them after reading ? In first case you will run out of memory either way, in second case may be you could do a `fopen` and `fscanf` line-by-line (i.e. buffering only small part of the file in memory)

Comment: Note that this also depends on your data types, `datetime` fields will take more memory than doubles, so if you can store the data as `datenum` instead you will have some saving. `table` variables will also be slightly less memory efficient than raw `double` matrices

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, first loading whole file content in memory is indeed in general a bad idea especially if it is a very large file (Its whole content may even may not fit at all in memory available). One would do so to limit disk access or when processing file by chunk is complex coding compare to just get it all first and then process it (as long as it is of reasonable size).

Another issue is, whatever file content is read in a raw or by chunk, do one need to keep all "values" inside the file as individually "values" in memory too ? If they need to be kept individually, one will run out of memory either way. In case one can "forget" about data or just reload part of them when required, it becomes more complex coding but one can get around large files.

Lets assume in your case, that file content is real-time acquisition of sensors values and that you just need to average them to reduce memory footprint. You can do a `fopen` and `fgetl` to get its content line-by-line. Note that, while `fgetl` is line-by-line, operating system maintains a buffer for you in memory so there is no disk access for each and every line.

Here is a full example:

- I'm using a regular expression to describe the kind of line I'm looking for in the file
- In `preallocateData` subfunction:

  - I move to the beginning of the file
  - I read line by line until finding the first interesting one
  - I then quickly move until almost the end of file using `fseek`
  - I read line by line until finding the last interesting one
  - From first/last read timestamps and averaging size I want I can determine how big will be my matrix in the end and preallocate it for speed optimization.
- In `doAveraging` subfunction:

  - I move to the beginning of the file
  - I read line by line and accumulate values until timestamp difference is larger than averaging duration I chose
  - I store averaged values in my preallocated dataset
  - I trim data for unused preallocated block if required
- Note that:

  - Code should work even if sensors stop sending values for a while (i.e. large gap in timestamps)
  - Code can average data at fixed time slots from the origin or for a period of time just after last recorded data (see `fixBinAveragingMode`)
  - Final timestamp list may not be linear (especially if there is gaps in original timestamp or if you don't use `fixBinAveragingMode`). You can add call to `interp1` in the end of main function to remap averaged sensor values on linearly spaced time scale if more practical.

```
%
% PURPOSE:
%
%   Averages real-time sensor values.
%
% SYNTAX:
%
%   [timeNs, data] = AveragingSensorData(filename, avgDurationNs);
%
% INPUTS:
%
%   - 'filename': Text file containing real-time sensor data
%   - 'avgDurationNs': Averaging duration (in nanoseconds)
%
% OUTPUT:
%
%   - 'timeNs': (1 x ncount) vector representing time (in nanoseconds)
%   - 'data': (ncount x 4) representing averaged sensor values
%             * First column is channel0
%             * Second cilumn is channel1
%             * Third column is channel2
%             * Fourth column is ambient
%

%% ---
function [timeNs, data] = AveragingSensorData(filename, avgDurationNs)
%[
    if (nargin < 2), avgDurationNs = 1e9; end %0.01*1e9; end
    if (nargin < 1), filename = '.\data.txt'; end

    % Regular expression pattern describing the type of line we are looking for in the file
    % Means : 
    %   - Start of line
    %   - Whatever except ';', 
    %   - ';', 
    %   - one-to-many-digits, (i.e timestamp)
    %   - ';' 
    %   - one-to-many-digits (eventually prefixed with [+/-], (i.e. channel0)
    %   - ... etc ...
    pattern = '^[^;]*;([0-9]+);([+\-]?[0-9]+);([+\-]?[0-9]+);([+\-]?[0-9]+);([+\-]?[0-9]+);\s*$';

    % Minimal check
    if (~(isnumeric(avgDurationNs) && isscalar(avgDurationNs) && isreal(avgDurationNs) && (avgDurationNs > 0)))
        error('Are you''re kidding me ?');
    end

    % So first lets try opening the file for later line-by-line reading it 
    [fid, err] = fopen(filename, 'rt');
    if (fid <= 0), error('Failed to open file: %s', err); end
    cuo = onCleanup(@()fclose(fid)); % This will close the file all cases (normal termination, or exception, or even ctrl+c)

    % Here based on number of lines in the files and averaging duration we
    % estimate the final size of the data and preallocate them.
    % NB: Quick exit is easy cases when there is 0 or single data line
    [timeNs, data, canQuickExit] = preallocateData(fid, pattern, avgDurationNs);
    if (canQuickExit), return; end

    % Do the averaging really
    fixBinAveraginMode = false; % Is averaging at fix or floating time position ?
    [timeNs, data] = doAveraging(fid, pattern, avgDurationNs, fixBinAveraginMode, timeNs, data);   
end

%% ---
function [timeNs, data, canQuickExit] = preallocateData(fid, pattern, avgDurationNs)
%[
    % Go back to the beginning of the file
    frewind(fid);

    % Look for first and last interesting lines in the file
    % NB: This assumes timestamps are sorted in increasing order
    nothingYet = true;
    fastAndFurious = true;
    firstReadTokens = []; lastReadTokens = [];
    while(true)

        % Read line-by-line until finding something interesting or eof
        tline = fgetl(fid);
        if (~ischar(tline)), break; end
        tokens = regexp(tline, pattern, 'tokens');
        if (~isscalar(tokens)), continue; end

        if (nothingYet) % It is the first time we found some interesting line
            nothingYet = false;
            firstReadTokens = tokens;
            lastReadTokens = tokens;            
            if (fastAndFurious)
                % Ok, don't bother reading each line, move almost to the
                % end of file directly. NB: This can be risky if there is
                % many empty lines at the end of the file, or if all lines
                % are not of the same length
                fseek(fid, -3 * numel(tline), 'eof');                
            end            
        else % This is not the first time
            lastReadTokens = tokens;
        end

    end

    % Conversion of matched tokens timestamps
    firstReadTimestamp = []; lastReadTimestamp = [];
    if (~isempty(firstReadTokens)), firstReadTimestamp = str2double(firstReadTokens{1}{1}); end
    if (~isempty(lastReadTokens)), lastReadTimestamp = str2double(lastReadTokens{1}{1}); end     

    % Compute preallocation
    if (isempty(firstReadTimestamp)), 
        % Easy, not a single line of data in the whole file
        timeNs = zeros(1, 0);
        data = zeros(0, 4);        
        canQuickExit = true;
    elseif (isempty(lastReadTimestamp) || (abs(lastReadTimestamp - firstReadTimestamp) < 0.1)), 
        % Easy again, just one line of data in te whole file        
        timeNs = zeros(1, 1);
        data = [str2double(firstReadTokens{1}{2}), str2double(firstReadTokens{1}{3}), str2double(firstReadTokens{1}{4}), str2double(firstReadTokens{1}{5})];
        canQuickExit = true;
    else
        % Ok, lets allocate
        estimateBlockCount = ceil((lastReadTimestamp - firstReadTimestamp) / avgDurationNs);
        timeNs = zeros(1, estimateBlockCount);
        data = zeros(estimateBlockCount, 4);
        canQuickExit = false;
    end
%]
end

%% ---
function [timeNs, data] = doAveraging(fid, pattern, avgDurationNs, fixBinAveragingMode, timeNs, data)
%[
    % Go back to the beginning of the file
    frewind(fid);

    % Look for interesting lines till the end
    % NB: We assume timestamps are sorted in increasing order in the file
    idx = 0;
    nothingYet = true;    
    while(true)

        % Read line-by-line until finding something interesting
        tline = fgetl(fid);
        if (~ischar(tline)), break; end
        tokens = regexp(tline, pattern, 'tokens');
        if (~isscalar(tokens)), continue; end

        lastReadTimestamp = str2double(tokens{1}{1});
        if (nothingYet) 
            nothingYet = false;

            idx = idx+1;
            avgCount = 1;
            timeNs(idx) = lastReadTimestamp;
            nextStopTimestamp = lastReadTimestamp + avgDurationNs;
            avg = [str2double(tokens{1}{2}), str2double(tokens{1}{3}), str2double(tokens{1}{4}), str2double(tokens{1}{5})];
        elseif (lastReadTimestamp > nextStopTimestamp)    
            data(idx, :) = avg / avgCount;

            idx = idx+1;
            avgCount = 1;
            if (fixBinAveragingMode)
                % Fixed time slots from origin
                offset = mod(lastReadTimestamp - timeNs(1), avgDurationNs);
                timeNs(idx) = (lastReadTimestamp - offset);
                nextStopTimestamp = timeNs(idx) + avgDurationNs;
            else
                % Run timer for averaging immediately after receiving data
                timeNs(idx) = lastReadTimestamp;
                nextStopTimestamp = lastReadTimestamp + avgDurationNs;
            end            
            avg = [str2double(tokens{1}{2}), str2double(tokens{1}{3}), str2double(tokens{1}{4}), str2double(tokens{1}{5})];

        else
            avgCount = avgCount + 1;
            avg = avg + [str2double(tokens{1}{2}), str2double(tokens{1}{3}), str2double(tokens{1}{4}), str2double(tokens{1}{5})];
        end
    end
    if (~nothingYet)
        timeNs = timeNs - timeNs(1); 
        data(idx, :) = avg / avgCount;
    end

    % Trim unused preallocated data if required
    timeNs((idx+1):end) = [];
    data((idx+1):end, :) = [];           
%]
end
```

The code is also stored on GitHub: [Averaging sensor values collected in a very large file](https://gist.github.com/CitizenInsane/8ac116f08ddaae410c21ae0ae450ec93)